# Applying Facebook Login to iOS app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I need to copy said code

```
    #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

into my app delegate.m file as per Facebook's instructions.

However, I am using Swift not Objective-C and do I don't have .h and .m files for my app delegate (or anything else for that matter), is there any other way in which to import this into my app delegate.swift file?

Comment: So I am able to directly import this into my app delegate.swift file without any tinkering? Please pardon my lack of knowledge, Im somewhat new to these things

Answer (score 2):

No need to do that.

Drag the corresponding FBSDKCoreKit framework file in your Xcode project, then just do

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
```

in the Swift files.

No need for anything else.

The way you were referring to was for previous versions of the non-Swift SDK.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced#swift